# Streamlining paragraph styles in Photoshop projects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow

We're using Photoshop for big web projects, and often use more than one designer for different pages within the same web project. We use color swatches to get a consistent result across many different pages, and regardless of who's working on the Photoshop files.

However, we often end up with many different font-sizes and font-families. Does Photoshop allow us to create a predefined set of allowed fonts to use in our projects, so we can streamline that as well?

Is it possible to predefine text-styles in one place, and update all textfields using that predefined textstyle in one place (for example: font-size, font-family and color)?

Comment: Are you using Photoshop just for creating mockups or creating the webpages with slices? When you are actually creating the pages for the web. You use CSS to style the font-size, font-family and color. Is there a reason why you need that to be done in Photoshop? You can use character and paragraph styles to easily change text all over. I am not sure about have pre-defined fonts for a file. I am also not sure how you would manage the styles from different documents. You could start with a template file with all the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define *paragraph styles*.

Just go to Window -> Paragraph Styles. Start writing text and highlight it. Now you can click the "New"-Icon, thus creating a style. Doubleclik it and set everything you want.

Using this, you can create any number of styles (I like to name them p, h1, h2, h3...) and apply them to a paragraph by just cliking o the style name in the paragh style window.

All text live updated. When you change a style, all text that currently has that style will change.

Comment: Thank you! For enyone else who finds this question, have a look at this video: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-create-paragraph-style.html. It explains paragraph styles very well.